# Can you use React Server Components to protect certain parts of your code behind authentication?

Tags: reactjs, web, next.js, server, components

When using client components in React, the code for components and pages is bundled and sent to the client. This means that frontend code is visible for everyone that visits my web app routes, and there is no way to protect against someone "stealing" or reading your code.
Obfuscating and minimizing is not a valid protection against this. Hiding anything behind authentication or feature flags is impossible.

Using the Nextjs app router, and thus, serverside components, is it possible to protect your code behind an authentication system? With protect the code I mean:
If I don't want the user to see certain components and logic, then it should **never** under any circumstances be sent to the client (so not bundled either).

Example:
I create a page that is a server component:

```
import React from 'react';
import Testcomponent from './testcomponent';

export default function page() {

  if (true) {
    return <div>VISIBLE</div>
  }

  const testFunction2 = () => {
    console.log('this line of code should never be visible in the browser, no matter what.');
    const testVar2 = 11;
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <Testcomponent/>
    </div>
  )
}
```

This component imports a 'use client' component:

```
'use client'

import React from 'react'

export default function Testcomponent() {
  const testFunction = () => {
    console.log('this function should never be visible in the client.');
    const testVar = 1;
  };
  return (
    <div>TEST </div>
  )
}
```

As far as I can tell, this works, meaning I can not find the Testcomponent (or any of the underlying data and functions) in the client.
Can I trust that, if following the above logic with protecting components, the code will never be sent to the client? Or is this not the intended use case / will change sometime soon / is bypassable by the user?